# The name 'ShuffleList' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android

Только начал учить C#. Появилась вот такая ошибкa "The name does not exist in the current context"

```cs
List<string> answerList = ShuffleList.ShuffleListItems<string>(question.options);
```

Comment: приложи код к вопросу

Comment: Код приложил к вопросу

Comment: а где ты взял SuffleList? такого класса нет в шарпе, разве только нугет устанавливать

Comment: А причём тут [tag:c]?

Comment: @dIm0n убрал `c`, нельзя трогать святое без повода :)